# proofreading for positive definite matrix has positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$\vec{v}^{t}\textbf{A}\vec{v} > \textbf{0}\text{ and }\textbf{A}\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}\quad \Rightarrow \lambda>\textbf{0}\quad(\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}) $$

proof:
$$\vec{v}^{t}\textbf{A}\vec{v} > \textbf{0} \text{ and } \textbf{A}\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v} $$
$$\Rightarrow\vec{v}^{t}\lambda\vec{v} > \textbf{0} $$
$$\Rightarrow\lambda\vec{v}^{t}\vec{v} > \textbf{0} $$
$$\Rightarrow\lambda\langle v, v\rangle> \textbf{0} $$
$$\vec{v} \neq \vec{0}$$
$$\Rightarrow\langle v, v\rangle > \textbf{0} $$
$$\Rightarrow\lambda > \textbf{0}$$

Comment: Seems right to me..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Another perspective. Let $v_{min}$ be the unit norm eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_{min}$, the lowest eigenvalue. 
\begin{align}
0<\min_{||v||=1}v^TAv\leq v_{min}^TAv_{min}=\lambda_{min}
\end{align}
Can you prove the middle inequality is in fact an equality?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Everything is correct.